# Ubuntu breaks down on occasion

Tags: unity

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and on occasion everything breaks down (best I can place it in words). First UI elements disappears and the icons inside them go missing. What's left are black on the top and on the left side of my screen. When I take a look at my desktop, the vanilla orange folders loose their icons and my laptop starts to freeze. Sometimes I get lucky and open up a folder before it freezes only to be greeted with a "folder location not found" error. I even managed to open up a terminal once in which case no commands were responsive. Here's a photo I managed to capture:

[image: Image of desktop]

This issue happens around three times a day and is getting more frequent. It shouldn't be a hardware problem but I'm not so sure... Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Seems unlikely based on the symptoms you describe but overheating perhaps?  Might be worth running ClamAV to see if there is a virus or PuP there.  You should have it (or some AV software) installed already but if you don;t it's very easy to install.  I'd also run checkbox (also easy to install).  It's found and fixed a few really odd problems for me in the past.

Comment: ClamAV and antivirus isn't a default part of Ubuntu, @jones0610.  As well, explaining what checkbox and other things are would be better than just recommending the softwares without explanation.